# unique elements of list of lists

Tags: python, set

I have a list similar to the following (which I have conveniently converted tuple of tuples of tuples so that `set` can get the unique elements.

```
mylist = ((('pen','pineapple'),('apple','pen')),(('pineapple','pen')),(('apple','pen'),('pen','pineapple')))
set(mylist)

>>>
{(('pen', 'pineapple'), ('apple', 'pen')),
('pineapple', 'pen'),
(('apple', 'pen'), ('pen', 'pineapple'))}
```

However, the element `('apple', 'pen'), ('pen', 'pineapple') == ('pen', 'pineapple'), ('apple', 'pen')` as far as my application is concerned. Is there a quick `python` method to get the unique elements disregarding order of elements.

Edit 1: As pointed out in comments:
`(( 'pen', 'apple'), ('pen', 'pineapple')) != (('apple', 'pen'), ('pen', 'pineapple'))`. i.e. I do not want to rearrange the innermost tuples. However, it is ok to rearrange the middle level of tuples.

Btw I was hoping for something a bit pythonic (or fancier) than using sort and then using `set`.

Comment: Why didn't `set()` meet your needs?

Comment: Look at the output, it spat out `(('apple', 'pen'), ('pen', 'pineapple'))` as another element. As stated its equivalent to `(('pen', 'pineapple'), ('apple', 'pen'))`.

Comment: @StephenRauch because `(A, B)` is not the same as `(B, A)`, therefore `set()` accepted both.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I understand how set works...  But OP made comment about manipulating his tuples so the list would *work*.  Still doesn't explain why set() did not meet his needs.

Comment: I doubt he can articulate why `set()` didn't work.  If he knew _that_, he wouldn't have needed to ask us for help.

Comment: Does no one appreciate the PPAP reference?

Comment: I love PPAP example. AP is not the same as PA... it has to be in exact direction, see solution at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct6BUPvE2sM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a set of sets. Sets can only contain immutable objects, so you'll have to convert every tuple into a `frozenset` and then make a set out of it:

```
In [4]: set(map(frozenset, mylist))
Out[4]:
{frozenset({('apple', 'pen'), ('pen', 'pineapple')}),
 frozenset({'pen', 'pineapple'})}
```